# Angular2: using gzip files in production

Tags: angular, gzip, angular-cli, production-environment

I'm using angular-cli to compile my app. When running `ng build --prod` the gzip bundle files are created, but the index.html is still using the full-sized files. I tried running `ng build --prod --aot` and got the same result. How do I tell angular-cli to use .gz files in production?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using an obsolete version of the CLI: the newest ones don't generate the gzip files anymore.

To serve gzipped files, the browser must send a request with a header telling that it accepts gzipped responses, and the server must be configured to then gzip the files (or load the already gzipped files), and send the gzipped result, when the browser requests a file.

How to do that depends on your server.

But the index.html never refers to gzipped files. It refers to JS files. The browser asks for a JS file to the server and tells the server it accepts gzipped responses, and the server sends back the gzipped JS file, if it has been configured to do so.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that. Are browsers usually configured to accept gzipped files by default? Also, to serve my app I'm using a small nodejs/express application on Heroku. Do you think maybe this is where I should check for the gz headers?

Comment: Yes, most browsers accept gzipped responses by default. I know nothing about express, but I guess there must be some plugin/middleware allowing to do that for you. This one seems to be the official one: https://github.com/expressjs/compression

Comment: Cool. Got it to work. Why don't the newer angular-cli versions gzip files anymore?

Comment: Probably because most servers can generate these files on the fly anyway, and because if they don't, just using the gzip command (with the options you want) is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Incase if you are hosting your site on AWS you don't have to compress it on your own. I am using Cloud Front (CDN) and it does everything for me.

**How to Enable Gzip Compression in Cloud Front?**

Change *'Compress Objects Automatically'* from No to YES while setting up Cloud Front Distribution

For more details:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-gzip-compression-support-for-amazon-cloudfront/

Answer (score 1):

I created this mainly for testing purposes but if you want a simple Express.js server to run the app

1. https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0
2. `ng build` to build production files
3. `npm install express compression path --save`
4. create server.js inside `dist/[project-name]` and add:

   ```
    const express = require("express");
    const compression = require('compression'); // <--
    const path = require('path');
    const app = express();

    app.use(compression()); // <--

    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
    });

    app.use(express.static('.'))

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running http://127.0.0.1:${PORT}/`);
    });
   ```
5. cd dist/[project-name]
6. `node server.js`